# Remove Redirect on Main Menu Drupal 7

Tags: menu, hyperlink, drupal-7

It's hard to explain by words, so I'll just provide a screen shot for it.

[image]

Is there any other way to disregard the path on main menu on drupal?
So when I just click it, it won't happen anything, just a # sign.

Hope you understand, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Special Menu Items**](https://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module. Drupal will not allow you to use a special character like #,?,. etc by default in menu links.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact page you want it to lead to, you can enter the full  html e.g. html://www.yourdomain.com/my_page

But, I don't understand why you would be adding a link to a menu if you don't want it to be a link?

If you want to disable menu links (e.g. "home"), go to "/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu" and just disable them using the check boxes next to the menu entry.